# how to generate a .txt file from sql server and then print it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

After doing a multi-hour research in google i think i m more confused...I want to

a)generate a text file (.txt or .doc .pdf) from sql server via a stored procedure.The file  contains some table data in a simple layout format

and then

b)print this file to a network printer.

All the above via code.Is it possible?Any ideas?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: yes its possible............

Comment: Look at reporting services probably.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17531/How-to-Print-a-Document-from-SQL-Stored-Procedure

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried yourself? Basically you will get the data from the table, whether through a SP, standard SQL, LinQ, ... and when iterating over the results you write the data to a file using a Stream-object.

Comment: the data is already in sql server tables.my first step is to write a stored procedure that generates a text file.Then maybe implement a service that checks if a file is created and print it.But i don't know the exact way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to share my implementation as I struggled myself to find a proper solution

a)Extract table data to a simple .txt file with the help of bcp utility.
Inside the stored procedure write something similar to this

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [yourDatabase]..[yourTable]" queryout "C:\Folder\archive.txt" -T -w  -t ,'
```

I used a "," as a field terminator.
You can read more about bcp parameters here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

b)Now i have the raw data and i want to print it.I 've implemented a service which just checks if a new file was created.This is a nice tutorial http://midnightcubicle.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/creating-windows-service-in-c/

The service calls a new process that runs an .exe file that does the job.

Some things to notice:

-usually services run in local.If you want to print run your service in "user mode"
      Check your service's properties via services.msc

-Data extracted from bcp is in  "raw" format so if you want to give your text a nice layout  you have to read its content with StreamReader,save its data in memory (e.g objects in a list-every line is an object-every field a property) and then use string.Format and other formating techniques.

-You might see a completely different result in your windows console and in your printer.This is caused because your console uses fixed width fonts where your printer does not (at least by default). So spaces take up less space on your printer and your letters take up more or less space based on their actual width.Consider using Lucida Console or another fixed-width font.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXEC @rc = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell and call an exe to print the file